# Calling DialogFragment from ListView's contextMenu

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

there) In my app i use single `DialogFragment` for **adding** and **editing** items of the `ListView`stored in `ListFragment`. I'll also mention that my dialog uses **voice input** on some `EditText`s.

So, the issue is that dialog goes **invisible after voice recognizer activity returns result to it** (Well, actually it goes invisible right after the `startActivityForResult()` call). But the Dialog is still there! I know it, because when i rotate the screen it appears with the result returned by the **voice recognizer** activity! It happens only, when i call it from `ListView` item's **contextMenu** (to **edit item**). And when i call it from the **optionsMenu** (to **add item**) all goes fine.

Here's my `ProductDialogFragment.java`:

```
public class ProductDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements
        OnClickListener,
        OnItemSelectedListener,
        OnLongClickListener {
    private CustomDialog dialog;

    private EditText mProductName;
    private EditText mProductAmount;
    private Spinner mMeasuresSpinner;
    private Button mBtnOk;
    private Button mBtnCncl;
    private String mPassedName;
    private String mPassedAmount;
    private long mPassedMeasureId;
    private static long mEditedProdId;

    private static DBController mDBController;

    public static final String ADDED_PRODUCT_NAME = "com.zulfigarov.shoppingassistant_added_product_name";
    public static final String ADDED_PRODUCT_AMOUNT = "com.zulfigarov.shoppingassistant_added_product_amount";
    public static final String ADDED_PRODUCT_MEASURE = "com.zulfigarov.shoppingassistant_added_product_measure";
    public static final String EDITED_PRODUCT_ID = "com.zulfigarov.shoppingassistant_edited_product_id";

    public static final int CREATE_NEW_PRODUCT_REQUEST = 999;
    public static final int EDIT_PRODUCT_REQUEST = 888;
    public static final int CALL_VOICE_RECOGNITION = 606;

    public static ProductDialogFragment newInstance() {
        ProductDialogFragment frag = new ProductDialogFragment();


        return frag;
    }

    public static ProductDialogFragment newInstance(long product_id, String product_name, String product_amount, long product_measure_id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();


        args.putString(ADDED_PRODUCT_NAME, product_name);
        args.putString(ADDED_PRODUCT_AMOUNT, product_amount);
        args.putLong(ADDED_PRODUCT_MEASURE, product_measure_id);

        ProductDialogFragment frag = new ProductDialogFragment();

        frag.setArguments(args);

        return frag;
    }

    public void setResult(int resultCode, int requestCode) {
        if ((getTargetFragment() == null)
                || (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED))
            return;

        Intent data = new Intent();
        String prodName;
        float prodAmount;
        long measureId = mMeasuresSpinner.getSelectedItemId();

        prodName = mProductName.getText().toString();

        prodAmount = Float.valueOf((mProductAmount.getText().toString() + "f"));

        data.putExtra(ADDED_PRODUCT_NAME, prodName);
        data.putExtra(ADDED_PRODUCT_AMOUNT, prodAmount);
        data.putExtra(ADDED_PRODUCT_MEASURE, measureId);


        if (requestCode == EDIT_PRODUCT_REQUEST) {
            data.putExtra(EDITED_PRODUCT_ID, mEditedProdId);
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(EDIT_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
                    resultCode, data);
        } else {
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(CREATE_NEW_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
                    resultCode, data);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        dialog = new CustomDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setCustomView(R.layout.add_new_item, getActivity());
        dialog.setTitleColor("#FFFFFF");
        dialog.setDividerColor("#FFFFFF");
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_new);

        View root = dialog.getCustomView();

        mProductName = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        mProductName.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        mProductAmount = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.product_amount);

        mBtnOk = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.add_new_product_button);
        mBtnOk.setOnClickListener(this);

        mBtnCncl = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.cancel_product_creation);
        mBtnCncl.setOnClickListener(this);

        mMeasuresSpinner = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.measures_spinner);

        mDBController = DBController.getController(getActivity());

        String[] from = {ProductDBHelper.MeasuresTable.COLUMN_TITLE};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mDBController.getMeasuresCursor(), from, to);
        mMeasuresSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mMeasuresSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        mMeasuresSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Bundle args = getArguments();

        if (args != null) {
            dialog.setTitle("Edit Selected Product");
            mBtnOk.setText("Apply");

            mPassedName = args.getString(ADDED_PRODUCT_NAME);
            mPassedAmount = args.getString(ADDED_PRODUCT_AMOUNT);
            mPassedMeasureId = args.getLong(ADDED_PRODUCT_MEASURE);

            mProductName.setText(mPassedName);

            mMeasuresSpinner.setSelection((int) (mPassedMeasureId - 1));

        } else
            dialog.setTitle("Add New Product");

        setCancelable(false);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.add_new_product_button): {
                if ((mProductName.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        || (mProductAmount.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "It seems you've forgot to write something!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    if (getArguments() != null) {
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, EDIT_PRODUCT_REQUEST);
                    } else
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,
                                CREATE_NEW_PRODUCT_REQUEST);


                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                break;
            }

            case (R.id.cancel_product_creation): {
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Log.d("shoppingAssistant", "onDismiss");
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {


        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mProductAmount.setText(mPassedAmount);
            mPassedAmount = "";
        } else
            mProductAmount.setText("");

        if (mDBController.checkIfMeasureDecimal(id)) {
            mProductAmount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
                    | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

        } else {
            mProductAmount.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == ProductDialogFragment.CALL_VOICE_RECOGNITION) {

            if (data != null) {
                String matches = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)
                        .get(0);
                mProductName.setText(matches);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to get your voice input",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                    "Tell me your product name:");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);

            startActivityForResult(intent, ProductDialogFragment.CALL_VOICE_RECOGNITION);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch"));

            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }


        return false;
    }
}
```

and here's the `ListFragment` (where calling **voice recognizer** from `ProductDialogFragment` from items **context menu** makes `DialogFragment` invisible):

```
public class ProductListFragment extends ListFragment
{
    public static final String LIST_POS = "com.zulfigarov.shoppingassistant.list_id";
    private ProductList mList;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private DBController mDBController;
    private ProductAdapter adapter;
    private int sentPos;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        Log.d("shoppingAssistant", "ProductListFragment.onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        sentPos = args.getInt(LIST_POS);

        mDBController = DBController.getController(getActivity());

        mCursor =  mDBController.getListCursorByPos(sentPos);

        if (getListAdapter() != null)
            getListAdapter().clear();

        String prod_title = ProductDBHelper.ProductsTable.COLUMN_TITLE,
                prod_amount = ProductDBHelper.ProductsTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT,
                prod_state = ProductDBHelper.StatesTable.COLUMN_STATE,
                measures_title = ProductDBHelper.MeasuresTable.COLUMN_TITLE;


        String[] from = {prod_title, prod_amount, prod_state, measures_title};
        int[] to = {R.id.prod_title, R.id.prod_count, R.id.is_bought, R.id.prod_measure};


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.prod_list_item, mCursor, from, to);

        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)
            {
                if(view.getId() == R.id.is_bought)
                {
                    String state = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    Log.d("shoppingAssistant", state);
                    if(state.equals(ProductDBHelper.StatesTable.STATE_BOUGHT))
                        ((CheckBox)view).setChecked(true);
                    else
                        ((CheckBox)view).setChecked(false);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    @Override
    public ProductAdapter getListAdapter()
    {
        return adapter;
    }

    private long mSelectedProductId;

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        if (v.getId() == getListView().getId())
        {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            mSelectedProductId = acmi.position;

            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(
                    R.menu.context_menu_for_list, menu);
        }

    }

    public void showAddingProductDialog()
    {
        ProductDialogFragment dialog = ProductDialogFragment
                .newInstance();

        dialog.setTargetFragment(ProductListFragment.this,
                ProductDialogFragment.CREATE_NEW_PRODUCT_REQUEST);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        dialog.show( ft, "add_new_product");

    }

    public void showEditingProductDialog(long product_id)
    {
        String prod_title = ProductDBHelper.ProductsTable.COLUMN_TITLE,
               prod_amount= ProductDBHelper.ProductsTable.COLUMN_AMOUNT,
               product_measure_id = ProductDBHelper.ProductsTable.COLUMN_MEASURE_ID;


        Cursor c = mDBController.getProductById(product_id);

        ProductDialogFragment dialog = ProductDialogFragment
                .newInstance(
                        product_id, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(prod_title)),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(prod_amount)),
                        c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(product_measure_id)));

        dialog.setTargetFragment(ProductListFragment.this,
                ProductDialogFragment.EDIT_PRODUCT_REQUEST);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        dialog.show( ft, "edit_product");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case (ProductDialogFragment.CREATE_NEW_PRODUCT_REQUEST) :
            {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    String prodName = data
                            .getStringExtra(ProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_NAME);

                           float prodAmount = data
                            .getFloatExtra(ProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_AMOUNT, 0f);

                    long prodMeasure = data
                            .getLongExtra(ProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_MEASURE, 1);


                    addNewProduct(prodName,prodAmount, prodMeasure);

                }
                break;
            }

            case (ProductDialogFragment.EDIT_PRODUCT_REQUEST) :
            {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    String prodName = data
                            .getStringExtra(ProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_NAME);

                           float prodAmount = data
                            .getFloatExtra(ProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_AMOUNT, 0f);

                    long prodMeasure = data
                            .getLongExtra(ProductDialogFragment.ADDED_PRODUCT_MEASURE, 1);

                    editProductAtIndex(mSelectedProductId,prodName, prodAmount, prodMeasure );

                }
                break;
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



    public void addNewProduct(String title, float amount, long measureId)
    {
        long list_id = mDBController.getListIdByPos(sentPos);
        mDBController.addProductToList(list_id, title, amount, measureId);

        mCursor.requery();
    }

    public void editProductAtIndex(long product_id, String product_name, float product_amount, long product_measure_id)
    {
        mDBController.editProductById(product_id, product_name, product_amount, product_measure_id);
        mCursor.requery();
    }

    public void clearList()
    {
        mDBController.clearCurrentList(sentPos);
        mCursor.requery();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        long product_id = acmi.id;



        if (getUserVisibleHint())
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case (R.id.clear_current_list) :
                {
                    clearList();
                    break;
                }

                case (R.id.delete_current_list_item) :
                {
                    mDBController.deleteProductById(product_id);
                    mCursor.requery();
                    break;
                }

                case (R.id.edit_selected_item) :
                {
                    mSelectedProductId = product_id;
                    showEditingProductDialog(product_id);
                    break;
                }

                case (R.id.add_new_product):
                {
                    showAddingProductDialog();
                    break;
                }
            }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setDivider(null);
        lv.setDividerHeight(0);
        lv.setSelector(R.drawable.list_item_selector);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        CheckBox isBought = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.is_bought);
        isBought.setChecked(!isBought.isChecked());

        mDBController.setBought(isBought.isChecked(), id);
        mCursor.requery();
    }

    public static ProductListFragment newInstance(int pos)
    {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(LIST_POS, pos);
        ProductListFragment prodListFrag = new ProductListFragment();
        prodListFrag.setArguments(args);

        return prodListFrag;
    }

    class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>
    {

        public ProductAdapter(ProductList list)
        {
            super(getActivity(), 0, list);
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.prod_list_item, null);

            Product prod = getItem(position);

            TextView prodTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.prod_title);
            prodTitle.setText(prod.getTitle());

            TextView prodCount = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.prod_count);
            prodCount.setText(prod.getAmount() + " " + prod.getMeasure());

            CheckBox isBought = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.is_bought);
            isBought.setChecked(prod.isBought());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
    //
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {

        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("shoppingAssistant","ProductListFragment" + this.getTag() +".onDestroy()");
    }

}
```

What should i do to fix this?

Comment: Whats is the error ? show log

Comment: There's no exceptions. My dialog turns invisible after i call startActivityForResult() from it. And i need toreturn to it to finish input. And it happens only if the dialog has been called from the contextMenu. If the dialog has been called from the optionsMenu all goes fine